# getting uid of users from firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an android app in kotlin and i created a login and register with firebase authentication, now when i want to access the users info in the database using the **uid** i got with this **FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString()** i noticed that the current **uid** is deferent from the **uid** that the function **createUserWithEmailAndPassword()** gave the users when it created them and inserted the to the database.
my question is how do i get the original **uid** from **createUserWithEmailAndPassword()**.

i was thinking of saving the **uid** in a global string in the function **createUserWithEmailAndPassword()** but I'm sure there's a better idea .

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to get the uid from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`?

Comment: It's quite possible that the Firebase SDK is automatically picking up the Android user's Google account and automatically signing that in for you. Check your Firebase Auth console and compare the two user entries.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Rosário asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Since you're tagged your question with `Kotlin`, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).